# iOS/Swift UIImageView (.jpg) not recognizing my tap gesture?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a simple block of code to play a sound when my image gets tapped. However, when I tap my image, the tap isn't even recognized.

I believe this to be true because println in the handleTap function doesn't print anything when the image is tapped.

Can anyone give me some insight as to where the problem might be?

```
var coinSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wavSampleSound", ofType: "wav")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadSound()

    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    gesture.delegate = self
    myImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}
func loadSound() {
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: coinSound, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

}
func handleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let playsSound = self.audioPlayer.play()
    println("\(playsSound)")
}


@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the default setting of the `userInteractionEnabled` of `UIImageView` is `false`. You want to set it to `true`.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! While your thank you note is nice, on SOF we also click do click the checkmark for the accepted answer.

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks!